# Бесконечный аякс запрос

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице несколько пользовательских фреймов. Есть аякс запрос (GET), который получает данные передаваемые сервером. Ответ сервер получает по сложной цепочке --от датчиков. Проблема в том. что само получение данных на клиенте может занимать до полуминуты, может быть ответа вовсе не будет. при этом все это время клиент ждет. (из -за этого тормозит окончательная прорисовка страницы с этим целевым фреймом) Вопрос в том как правильно реализовать способ показа пользователю возможности оставаться на странице и продолжать ждать выполнения. либо предложить ему загрузить  страницу без этого запроса

Comment: Сами Ajax запросы являются асинхронными, просто видимо вы либо используете один запрос на все, либо их как-то синхронизируете. В общем ответ - грузите страницу и потом только догружайте данные в нужный фрейм другим запросом (повесив на фрейм плашку ожидания).

Comment: И у вас схема немного не для Ajax. Если "ответ" на сервере появляется вне зависимости от запросов клиента, то Вам скорее стоит посмотреть в сторону WebSocket. Сервер получил данные с датчиков? Оповещаем об этом всех клиентов

Comment: WebSocket уже используем. Вопрос в том, что при посещении страницы имеется множество запросов к серверу для генерации различных фреймов. Отрисовка последнего возможна когда будут получены данные для этого конкретного фрейма от привязанного к нему аякс запроса. Нужен совет, если запрос выполняется с длительным ожиданием возможно ли его отложить показав пользователю возможность оставаться на странице и ждать когда придет ответ либо получить то что есть (текущие фреймы) без этого запроса.